# Renaming class causes IBOutlet connection to fail

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uilabel, iboutletcollection

I renamed a class, which happened to have an outlet connection to a label called *mainLabel* in a storyboard file. When I run my program, it crashes and gives me the error: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainLabel".

Other SO answers have shown this to be caused by a bad outlet connection, so I removed the connection and removed any lose ends. When trying to reconnect the label to an outlet in my code, I get the error **Could not insert new outlet connection:** *Could not find any information for the class named CourseTableViewCell*

Other SO answers have provided solutions which I have tried and haven't worked including:

- Deleting the reference to the file and re-adding it
- Cleaning the project
- Deleting the derived data folder
- deleting the label and re-adding it
- Dragging from the code to storyboard rather than vice-versa

I made sure that the correct file name was listed in the identity inspector, under "Custom Class". If anybody has any other ideas, please let me know!

I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Have you updated the custom class property for the cell in the storyboard to reflect the new class name

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I made sure to do that.

Comment: I find the assistant view can be difficult some times. You can just add the @IBOutlet to the source file manually and then drag from "new referencing outlet" to the object in the navigator in Interface Builder and the outlet should appear.

Comment: @Paulw11 This would allow me to create the connection, but my program would crash and give me the original error.

Comment: You may have a reference somewhere else to mainLabel that you don't know about. If you right-click on the storyboard you can open as "source" and search for "mainLabel"

Comment: @Paulw11 In the connections inspector for the label, there isn't a single active connection of any kind. I've also commented out the only other references to the label in my project and still no luck

Comment: Did you search ⌘F in the source view for **mainLabel**

Comment: Yes. There is no instance of mainLabel in the source view, nor anywhere else in the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116762/discussion-between-paulw11-and-lahav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps are what you need to do to find existing IBOutlet / IBAction from and object. Be it `label`, `button`, etc. And how to remove it.

1. Open `Main.storyboard`. The `Document outline window` should be visible by default on the left of your storyboard window. If not, click the icon on left of the storyboard window, next to the `View As: iPhone 7`.
2. Select the object in `storyboard`, it's easier to find and then select it from the `document outline` of the `storyboard`.
3. Open the `Utility window` if not yet open on the most right side. Use shortcut key `Cmd-Option-0` (command-option-zero), to toggle open/close of the utility window.
4. Open the connection inspector by click on `right arrow` icon (top right most icon). Remove any unwanted IBOutlet / IBAction or any other connection you want to remove by clicking on the `x` icon next to the connection.
5. Recreate the connection. You could also drag directly from the `circle` next to the `element` in the `connection window` for a particular `object`. Else add the connection the way you have been doing for now.

As for the Class file and other coding file. You could just comment out the lines that previously have `IBAction` or `IBOutlet`. And retype the same line manually (don't `cut and paste`). Add back the connection from `storyboard`, and you should be good. Don't forget to delete the lines you commented out that you don't need anymore.