# when i start the app i see a white screen and tells me this error, how can i fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode

when i start the app i see a white screen and tells me this error, how can i fix it? the error appears in this line:

![myLabel.alpha = 0]

the error is Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode0x0)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
          myLabel.alpha = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Where you declared myLabel?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
  in this line, it's under the parentheses

Comment: Did you checked it's outletted properly?check IBOutlet connect with interface builder

Comment: how can i do? where  do i have to write myLabel.alpha=0?

Comment: sorry but i'm new with this program, how can i do?

Comment: Go to interface builder,right click viewcontroller you can able to see the property called myLabel.Right clcik and drag the outlet connection into your label which is shown in view.

Comment: ok i did, but now the program tells me Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: @Ludo7 The error in the console usually means you need to restart your device, restart Xcode or restart your Mac. Or some combination of those.

Although, that's not usually associated with a SIGABRT, but give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Your @IBOutlet must has become invalid. Maybe you rename it after connecting it or other reason.  You should remove the existing one and recreate again. 
 Please check [my answer in other thread on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233516/8079120).

Comment: If this solve your problem, please accept the answer.